# Реализация поиска на сайте, правильная SQL инструкция, PDO PHP

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Пытаюсь составить правильную SQL инструкцию для реализации поиска на сайте, в таблице около сорока столбцов, поиск нужно вести только по двум полям, первое производитель продукта, втрое название продукта. Пользователь набирает некоторый ряд символов и отправляет их на сервер ниже представляю код того что я делаю с полученными данными

```
//Подготовка поисковой строки
$search = trim(substr($this -> nameProduct, 0)); 
$search = preg_replace("#\#s=#msi", "", $search);
$search = preg_replace("/[^\w\x7F-\xFF\s]/", " ", $search);
$search = preg_replace("#  +#msi", " ", $search);
//В бой
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT  `product_type`, `name_product` FROM `table_smartfoni` WHERE `product_type` LIKE ? OR `name_product` LIKE ?");
$sth->execute(array($search, $search));                
$array_3 = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Проблема заключается в том что поиск осуществляется только по абсолютному совпадению, то есть, если скажем в строке name_product храниться название скажем состоящее 100 символов то поисковый запрос тоже должен состоят из того же количества и типа символов для абсолютного совпадения, я бы хотел реализовать выборку из БД по скажем заранее не определённого количеству и ряду символов, поиск должен осуществлялся по части строки или даже подстроки, одним словом надо чтобы возвращались все строки в хранимых данных которых есть совпавшие ряди символов с поисковой строкой

Comment: Для частичного совпадения Вам только-то и нужно добавить в условие `LIKE` символ `%`. Если нужно чтобы искалась только строка начинающаяся на поисковое слово то `LIKE слово%`, если наоборот заканчивалось то `LIKE %слово`, ну а если чтобы строка содержала то само собой `LIKE %слово%`

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста а как это должно быть в инструкции, не понимаю куда именно вставит символы  
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT  `product_type`, `name_product` FROM `table_smartfoni` WHERE `product_type` LIKE ? OR `name_product` LIKE ?");

Comment: Добавьте либо к `$search` - `$search .= "%";` либо прямо в запрос `LIKE ?%` в зависимости от того как Вы будете искать - см. пример выше. А лучше почитайте как работает `LIKE`  в документации к используемой Вами СУБД. `ANSI92` они конечно все поддерживают, но иногда есть мелкие различия в каждом конкретном случае.

Comment: $search = $search .= "%"; Спасибо, надо было дать ответ на вопрос, я бы поставил лайк и +1 вам, работает фиговина

Comment: Не за что. Не ради лайков помогаем :) С Вас помощь кому-то еще на этом сайте в вопросах которых Вы хорошо разбираетесь :)